# Microphone's state

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am writing an application that uses MediaRecorder for recording audio. ( I use Android 2.1 )

1. Before start recording I want to know the microphone's state (is it busy or no)?
2. If the microphone busy, can I get exclusive access to it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my experience, if an app doesn't release the mic then you won't be able to access it.  The flip side of this, however, is once you have a lock on it other apps can't steal it from you (unless your app gets destroyed in the background by the OS).

Comment: Thanks Aaron C! You answered the second part of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to 1 question:
After reading many articles I realized that it was impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I show the way I solve this problem. Maybe someone will need this help. Note: it's a dirty way but it worked for me.

You can **try/catch** MediaRecorderObject.start(). You will get an exception if the mic is busy

```
MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

try {
        myAudioRecorder.prepare();
        myAudioRecorder.start();

    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mic in use", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```